# Custom counter using prometheus not visible on /actuator/prometheus

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to add custom metrics in my spring-boot application. I have looked at numerous examples and still, I'm failing to add a custom Counter.

**application.properties**

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
```

**code**

```
static final Counter requests = 
Counter.build().namespace("java").name("requests_total").help("Total requests.")
.register();

@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/test")
public int processRequest() {
    requests.inc();
    return (int) requests.get();
}
```

I can see the counter value increasing when I access the API. The problem is that I cannot find my newly created metrics on `http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus` and on the prometheus `:9090` page. So I figure the counter is not getting registered(??). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. Spring will automatically find the collector registry and wire it.

```
@Component
public class CustomeCounter {

Counter mycounter;

public CustomCounter(CollectorRegistry registry) {
 mycounter = Counter.build().name("test").help("test").register(registry);
}

public void incrementCounter() {
 mycounter.inc();
}
}


@Component
public class Test{

@Resource
private CustomCounter customCounter;

public void testInc() {
customCounter.incrementCounter();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user3310115 this works. Autowired CollectorRegistry and started seeing data on Prometheus endpoint. There seems to be a typo in line 2 where you intended 'CustomCounter' but it's 'CustomeCounter'.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the Prometheus Java API directly. The Counter you create is registered with the default `CollectorRegistry` of the Prometheus Java API but it is not registered with Micrometer as it is instantiating its own `CollectorRegistry` and thus your Counter is not shown there.

You should be using the Micrometer `Counter` API instead of directly using the Prometheus Java API. This has the added benefit that you can exchange your monitoring backend without any changes to your instrumentation code at all.

Additionally, it seems you would like to measure HTTP requests. These are usually automatically timed. Have a look for a metric family called `http_server_requests_seconds_[count,sum,max]` in your `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint.